# State and Prove Tarski-Vaught Test

Tags: logic

Sorry if this is a silly thing to ask here, but with no logic textbook available to me I'm confused about the Tarski-Vaught Test, including what exactly it is and how to prove it. I can't find any clear statements about this online, so if you could direct me with a link that would be helpful as well! Thanks!

Comment: You can find the statement on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_equivalence#Tarski.E2.80.93Vaught_test

Comment: Thanks! Any thoughts on where to find a proof, anyone?

Comment: Goggle led me to https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Tarski-Vaught_Test , which may well include a proof - hard for me to be sure since all the math I see there is $Math Processing Error$.

Comment: I did browse but was worried that it wasn't necessarily correct/complete as there were a lot of problems with the proof labeled on the page... I'll try to work my way through it as best as possible to figure it out though!